# Python: Socket doesn't want to shutdown() and setsockopt() is ignored? (Problem debugging)

Tags: python, sockets

## Edited

Original question was about trouble with reconnecting (close() and shutdown() confusion). The below code is the working code (fixed)
For Googler's, this script is an IRC bot. Feature list:

- Keep reconnecting until connection available
- If assigned nick is already taken, puts string behind name (repeats until success)
- Listens to PING and responds with PONG
- Can listen to commands and respond
- If connection is lost, the bot will try to reconnect (if no information is received, no PING, in 5 mins, it treats the connection as if it was disconnected)

That is about it :)

Full Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
import socket
import string
import os
import platform
import time

# Variables
HOST = "irc.server.net"
PORT = 6667
NICK = "Nickname"
IDENT = "Nickname"
REALNAME = os.getenv('USER')
CHAN = "##Channel"
readbuffer = ""

# The Connection itself
keep_connecting = True
while keep_connecting:
    irc = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    irc.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    irc.settimeout(300)
    try:
        irc.connect((HOST, PORT))
        pass
    except socket.gaierror:
        print "No connection, attempting to connect again"
        time.sleep(5)
        continue
    print "Sending info..."
    irc.send("NICK %s\r\n" % NICK)
    irc.send("USER %s %s bla :%s\r\n" % (IDENT, HOST, REALNAME))
    irc.send("JOIN :%s\r\n" % CHAN)
    # Initial msg to send when bot connects
    irc.send("PRIVMSG %s :%s\r\n" % (CHAN, "TehBot: "+ NICK + " Realname: " + REALNAME + " ."))
    while True:
        try:
            data = irc.recv(4096)
            print data
            # If disconneted from IRC
            if len(data) == 0:
                print "Length of data == 0 ?..."
                break
            # If Nick is in use
            if data.find (NICK + " :Nickname is already in use") != -1:
                NICK = NICK + str(time.time())[5:-3]
                break
            # Ping Pong so we don't get disconnected
            if data[0:4] == "PING":
                irc.send ("PONG " + data.split() [ 1 ] + "\r\n")
        except socket.timeout:
            print "Socket timeout!"
            irc.close()
            break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most probably because you're switching off wi-fi and the interface is removed from system so you get something like *Can't assign requested address*. You would get such an error while trying to bind to non-existing local address.

The other thing is you won't be able to reconnect on the same socket after calling `close` as it releases all resources associated to the socket.

Comment: Hmm, how would you suggest I go about reconnecting to the socket then if I still disconnect the same way? If I can't shutdown() or close() the socket if the disconnect happens this way?

Comment: You always can call `close` as it tells OS to remove it from resources. Just don't call `shutdown`.

Comment: @Chrules, also if you want to disconnect after getting timeout, why bother receiving all data just to ignore it? Call `irc.close()` after getting timeout and that's all. Calling `shutdown` after removing interface won't help much as well, as there is no way you can send this information to remote side.

Comment: Yeah, I get that now, but for some reason I still got the error msg of the socket being connected when only using close(), hence I tried to use shutdown() before so that close() wouldn't just wait. Dunno if that was just an irregularity, but will try to run the code agian :)

Comment: You probably didn't call `close` at all as you would get some error about file descriptor (as you can't connect again after calling close, move `irc = socket(...)` at the beginning of your loop). I suspect you just got empty string from `recv` so you tried to reconnect (but you can't do this either; you have to close the socket and create new one). Try to simplify your program flow a little bit.

Comment: Ahhhhh, frik ^^ Fairly new at playing with sockets :P, well, the problem was fixed by moving in the irc = socket(...) into the top of my loop. For some reason I just figured it would create a new instance simply from the irc.connect() , but apparently I was wrong. Thx for the help :)